# Go to next in list if statement is true

Tags: python

So let's say I have a list looking like this:

```
x_list = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
y_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I then want something like this:

```
for x in x_list:
    for y in y_list:
        if x - y == 0:
            stop and go to next in x_list
```

So basically, do the x and y loops until some statement is true, and then stop the y-loop and move on to next item in x_list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `break` statement here.

> terminates the nearest enclosing loop

```
for x in x_list:
    for y in y_list:
        if x - y == 0:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer is already given by @Denver Dang. However, try the list com>>>

```
>>> x_list = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> y_list = [1, 4, 3, 4, 10]
>>> [(x-y == 0) for x,y in zip(x_list,y_list)]

[False, True, False, False, True]
```